# Fold current level blocks (siblings elements) in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Assume you are in a `ul` list and you want to fold all `li` elements in that `ul`, i.e. how could fold all same level elements using PhpStorm?

```
<ul>
            <li class="webdesign">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c9MnSeYYtYY?autoplay=1" rel="portfolio" class="folio iframe">
                    <img src="portfolio/3-thumb.jpg" alt="" >
                    <h2 class="title">Snow time</h2>
                    <span class="categorie">Webdesign</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="photoghraphy">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="portfolio" target="_new">
                    <img src="portfolio/2-thumb.jpg" alt="" >
                    <h2 class="title">Help us</h2>
                    <span class="categorie">Photography</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="animation print">
                <a href="portfolio/4.jpg" rel="portfolio" class="folio">
                    <img src="portfolio/4-thumb.jpg" alt="" >
                    <h2 class="title">Sunshine</h2>
                    <span class="categorie">Print / Animation</span>
                </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well -- `Alt+Click` to fold `<ul>` element -- then unfold in normal way (just `Click`)

Comment: `Alt+Click` don't fold for me, it just add a caret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt + Click</kbd> on fold sign `[-]` (on the edge of the editor area) to fold `<ul>` element ... and then unfold it in a normal way (just <kbd>Click</kbd>).

---

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/code-folding.html#folding_means

> If you hold the `Alt` key and click `[+]`/`[-]` icons the region is collapsed or expanded recursively, i.e. along with all its subordinate regions.

So the idea behind is: collapse element and all children and then expand just top level element.

---

**P.S.** Instead of <kbd>Alt + Click</kbd> (which involves mouse usage) you can use just keyboard shortcut for `Collapse Recursively` action.

Nuance with keyboard only shortcut is: you have to place caret on that top line first .. which also may involve few key presses.